# Angularjs:datepicker validation

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

i am using this directive for datepicker

```
 define(['./module'], function(directives) {
'use strict';
directives.directive('ngDate', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        require: 'ngModel',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs, ngModelCtrl) {
            $(element).datepicker({
                dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy',
                onSelect: function(date) {
                    console.log(date);

                    ngModelCtrl.$setViewValue(date);
                    scope.$apply();
                }

            });
        }
    };
});
});
```

i have used it in html as follow

```
<input type='text' data-ng-model='fromDate' placeholder="dd-mm-yy" id="fromDate" data-ng-date=''  readonly='readonly'>

<input type='text' data-ng-model='toDate' placeholder="dd-mm-yy" id="toDate" data-ng-date='' readonly='readonly'>
```

here from date should not be greater than todate. how to validate that in angularjs? second datepicker should not display dates before selected date in to datepicker ie if 26th April is selected  in from datepicker than in to datepicker dates before 26th should not be displayed. how to achieve that?

Comment: This depends entirely on the datepicker component you use. Some of them support a `setMaxDate`, which you can then bind to a variable on your scope using a `scope.$watch`. Minor sidenote: you shouldn't put custom directives in the `ng` namespace, it's reserved for built-in directives!

Comment: thanks i will update directive name. maxDate is supported by jQueryUI library. but how to bind that? anything like this $scope.$watch('startdt', function(newval, oldval){
        if($scope.enddt < $scope.startdt) {
            $scope.enddt = '';
        };
    }); as shown in this fiddle? http://jsfiddle.net/9ezsJ/

Comment: @PriyaBhatt if you create a fiddle your answer will be answered much faster.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/priya78/kkMp4/